# Custom web server control fails when calling a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, custom-server-controls

I've created a web server control, it works fine. Problems start when I try calling an external web service. I am using a script manager and it's directed to the following location --> http:\localhost\UserNamesData.asmx.

My server control creates some html controls as well some javascript code. When the user clicks a submit button The javascript calls the external web service. I am using a script manager to register the service reference.

Now this seems to work when I put the web service inside the project in which the server control is later registered in (Meaning in my website) and when *inline script* is set to true. Though it does not work when my web service is not in the same project as my website.

I am using aspnet and c# 3.5

I have no idea what might cause it to act this way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you have to make sure that the webservice is in the same domain as the page containing the scriptmanager (see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx) for details).

Maybe if you can post some sample code, it will be easier to help.